# Jekyll array contains check

Tags: ruby, templates, jekyll, liquid

I've an array in my _config.yaml. Let's say

```
exclude_pages: [ "/404.html", "/search.html", "/atom.xml", "/rss.xml", "/index.html", "/sitemap.txt" ]
```

What I want to do is exclude these pages in the pages loop of site.pages. So following is the code that I'm trying.

```
{% for entry in site.pages %}
    {% if site.exclude_pages contains entry.url %}
        <!-- Do Nothing -->
    {% else %}
        <!-- Show Page -->
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But somehow it is not happening. All the pages are being ignored in this code.

Any idea what I'm missing here ?

Comment: Try to echo `entry.url` like: `puts "[#{entry.url}]"` to make sure there no superfluous invisible spaces etc.

Comment: I tried. The issue is `entry.url` showing up the exact string which is there in `exclude_pages` array. But the if condition check fails. I tried to display the boolean output of the condition. It is returning the whole array every time instead of any boolean value. Refere to the screenshot : http://imgur.com/8KR1pnO

Answer (score 11):

Try :

```
exclude_pages: [ "index.html", "anyfolder/index.html" ]
```

Then loop with **`entry.path`** not `entry.url`:

```
{% for entry in site.pages %}
    {% if site.exclude_pages contains entry.path %}
        <!-- Do Nothing -->
    {% else %}
        <!-- Show Page -->
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Did not find a luck in this either. The issue is I mentioned in the above comment. The if condition check is not returning any boolean value. Rather it's returning the whole array itself. Refer : http://imgur.com/8KR1pnO

Comment: Both code works here. Do you have github repository ?

Comment: Never mind. Got it working. It seems that sleep was fooling around with me. It was a coding error. Thanx anyways. :)

Comment: @UditDesai can you elaborate on what was causing the issue? I'm having just the same problem. When I output my index in the loop I'm seeing all of the paths I want to look in correctly, and when I output my `contains` variable, I'm seeing the correct string there as well (I even see where it should evaluate to true in the loop as it finds a match).

Answer (score 2):

According to [*template docs*](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#filters) you my try to use *Where Expression* with [`contains`](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/basics/operators#contains) and [`unless`](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/tags/control-flow-tags#unless).

```
{{ assign entries = site.pages | where_exp:"item", "unless item.url contains site.exclude_pages" }}
{% for entry in entries %}
   <!-- Show Page -->
{% endfor %}
```

See sample how a [live code](https://github.com/chetabahana/chetabahana.github.io/blob/eb2c3be19215c2956423ee9aa0423410681fc143/_includes/feed/json#L8) works to generate [feed.json](https://chetabahana.github.io/feed.json) in my github site.

Comment: I would love to have this syntax! however, it seems that it does not work at all.

Comment: It works in my jekyll site. I have edited my answer with sample of to a live code.